# Cannt run or build Docker images on CentOS 7

Tags: docker

I'm learning using Docker now, I've installed docker on my server(CentOS 7). But when I follow the offical tutorial, I meet one problem which fails me to continue:

```
mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay/7849ab40fd8072dcd724387dab14707bb4af0e94d9ab4f71795d0c478c3d49a9-init/merged/dev/shm: invalid argument
```

this appears when I build/run most images(few image that didnt fail is offical python:latest and hello-world)

What I'm trying to do is pulling offical image "docker/whalesay" and run it as follows:

```
docker run docker/whalesay
Unable to find image 'docker/whalesay:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/whalesay
e190868d63f8: Pull complete 
909cd34c6fd7: Pull complete 
0b9bfabab7c1: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
00bf65475aba: Pull complete 
c57b6bcc83e3: Pull complete 
8978f6879e2f: Pull complete 
8eed3712d2cf: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:178598e51a26abbc958b8a2e48825c90bc22e641de3d31e18aaf55f3258ba93b
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/whalesay:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay/fb4b7f34f0963d158856dadccec49963e47716865c83066f7e6eaf0bae057a13-init/merged/dev/shm: invalid argument.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Here is my docker info:

```
Containers: 5
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 5
Images: 4
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
Volume: local
Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
seccomp
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.702 GiB
Name: iZ25d1y69iaZ
ID: VJAP:FBMM:CQ5I:KIV5:FO47:VJUJ:ECU2:5TOS:JZBE:EUSH:HUFF:NCAZ
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I tried to search, not found the same issue. it looks like a file system problem, so here is my df -h and file -s /dev/vda1

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        40G  4.9G   33G  14% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  352K  1.9G   1% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           380M     0  380M   0% /run/user/1000
```

.

```
/dev/vda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=80b9b662-0a1d-4e84-b07b-c1bf19e72d97 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

I'm new to Docker, so this maybe same configuration problem or version issue, but i havnt find it out.

I appreciate any suggestions and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** [GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10294) with the discussion of this problem.

I remember there was an issue with 3.10 kernel and overlayfs/ext4/xfs filesystems, and some people noticed that it started working again with a more recent kernel (I think it was in 3.18 that the `overlayfs` module was added to the kernel).

So if upgrading the kernel is an option to you, you can check if `overlayfs+ext4` works.

If a kernel upgrade is not an option, then I guess your only option is to use another storage driver (`aufs` should not be available, so [device mapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/))

Comment: Thank you, I'll try both of the options and comment later to make this issue clear

Comment: Problem solved, and the solution is very simple and straight: changing storage driver type to devicemapper by adding --storage-driver=devicemapper works fine.

Comment: So this type of issues should be solved by exam local storage information(file system type, kernel verions etc.) and choosing one of those suitable storage driver.

Comment: Yes. Another option would be to blacklist the overlayfs module in the problematic setups. Then, when Docker is installed, it detects overlayfs is not available and selects a better storage driver.

Answer (score 4):

I was in SLES12 and i fixed the issue by

1. service stop docker
2. vi /etc/docker/daemon.json   (This is a new file)
3. Add following entry

> {
>     "storage-driver": "devicemapper"
>   }

4. service start docker

Comment: Worked for me on sath89/oracle-12c docker image